# Retrieve information in other CSS "methods" - HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to HTML (as you can tell from the title) but I do have some coding experience. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#rect {
width:20px;
height:40px;
}

div {
width: rect width;
height: rect height;
}
```

I know code in the div is completely wrong, it's just to give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. How would I get the code in div to retrieve and use the values in rect?

Comment: What you wrote is CSS, not HTML, and isn't a programming language. You need to look into JavaScript for this. jQuery can make things easier.

Comment: Visit http://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot refer to the value of a property of an element when setting a value for a property of another element – except in the case of nested elements in a sense (e.g., setting `font-size: 100%` on an element means using the value of the `font-size` property of the parent element).

What you can do, though, is to use multiple selectors in a rule. In your example, you can set

```
#rect, div {
width: 20px;
height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done just in CSS.  You could however, use JavaScript to accomplish this though.

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a lot of time!